# I'm having some trouble using x and y coordinates from touchesBegan as the center key in a CI filter

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to setup having the users tap a location in an image view and the X,Y of the tap becomes the center point (kCIInputCenterKey) of the current image filter in use.

These are my global variables:

```
var x: CGFloat = 0
var y: CGFloat = 0
var imgChecker = 0
```

This is my touchesBegan function that checks if the user is touching inside the image view or not, if not then sets the filter center key to the center of the image view:

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: self.imageView)


        if (touch.view == imageView){
            print("touchesBegan | This is an ImageView")
            x = position.x * 4
            y = position.y * 4
            imgChecker = 1

        }else{
            print("touchesBegan | This is not an ImageView")
            x = 0
            y = 0
            imgChecker = 0
        }


        print("x: \(x)")
        print("y: \(y)")
    }
}
```

As you can see I have the checker there to make the filter center appear in the middle of the image if inside the image view was not tapped. I'm also printing out the coordinates tapped to xCode's console and they appear without issue.

This is the part where i apply my filter:

```
currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIBumpDistortion")

        currentFilter.setValue(200, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        currentFilter.setValue(1, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)

        if imgChecker == 1 {
             self.currentFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: self.x, y: self.y), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey)
        }else{

        self.currentFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: currentImage.size.width / 2, y: currentImage.size.height / 2), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey)
        }

x = 0
        y = 0
        let beginImage = CIImage(image: currentImage)
        currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(currentFilter.outputImage!, from: currentFilter.outputImage!.extent)
        currentImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
        self.imageView.image = currentImage
```

This is the CGRect I'm using, ignore the "frame" in there, its just a image view in front of the first one that allows me to save a "frame" over the current filtered image:

```
func drawImagesAndText() {

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))

    img = renderer.image { ctx in
    let bgImage = currentImage
        bgImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))

      frames = UIImage(named: framesAr)
      frames?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))
    }

}
```

When I do set the x,y by tapping inside the image view, the center of the filter in the image view keeps appearing in the lower left hand side of it regardless of where I tapped inside. If i keep tapping around the image view, the center does seem to move around a bit, but its no where near where I'm actually tapping.

any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep two things in mind.

First (and I think you probably know this), the CI origin (0,0) is lower left, not top left.

Second (and I think this is the issue) UIKit (meaning UIImage and potentially CGPoint coordinates) are not the same as CIVector coordinates. You need to take the UIKit touchesBegan coordinate and turn it into the CIImage.extent coordinate.

EDIT:

All coordinates that follow are X then Y, and Width then Height.

After posting my comment I thought I'd give an example of what I mean by scaling. Let's say you have a UIImageView sized at 250x250, using a content mode of AspectFit, displaying an image whose size is 1000x500.

Now, let's say the touchesBegan is CGPoint(200,100). (NOTE: If your UIImageView is part of a larger superview, it could be something more like 250,400 - I'm working on the point **within** the UIImageView.)

Scaling down the image size (remember, AspectFit) means the image is actually centered vertically (landscape appearing) within the UIImageView at CGRect(0, 62.5, 250, 125). So first off, good! The touch point not only began within the image view, it also began wishing the image. (You'll probably want to consider the not-so-edge case of touches beginning outside of the image.)

Dividing by 4 gives you the scaled down image view coordinates, and as you'd expect, multiplying up will give you the needed vector coordinates. So a touchesBegan CGPoint(200,100) turns into a CIVector(800,400).

I have some code written - not much in the way of comments, done in Swift 2 (I think) and very poorly written - that is part of a subclass (probably should have been an extension) of UIImageView that computes all this. Using the UIImageView's bounds and it's image's size is what you need. Keep in mind - images in AspectFit can also be scaled up!

One last note on CIImage - extent. Many times it's a UIImage's size. But many masks and generated output may have an infinite eatent.

SECOND EDIT:

I made a stupid mistake in my scaling example. Remember, the CIImage Origin is **bottom left**, not **upper left**. So in my example a CGPoint(200,100), scaled to CGPoint(800,400) would be **CGVector(800,100)**.

THIRD EDIT:

Apologies for the multiple/running edits, but it seems important. (Besides, only the last was due my stupidity! Worthwhile, to note, but still.)

Now we're talking "near real time" updating using a Core Image filter. I'm planning to eventually have some blog posts on this, but the **real** source you want is [Simon Gladman](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/?view=magazine) (he's moved on, look back to his posts in 2015-16), and his eBook [Core Image for Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/core-image-for-swift/id1073029980?mt=13) (uses Swift 2 but most is automatically upgraded to Swift 3). Just giving credit where it is due.

If you want "near real time" usage of Core Image, you need to use the GPU. UIView, and all it's subclasses (meaning UIKit) uses the CPU. That's okay, using the GPU means using a Core Graphics, and specifically using a GLKView. It's the CG equivalent of a UIImage.

Here's my subclass of it:

```
open class GLKViewDFD: GLKView {
    var renderContext: CIContext
    var myClearColor:UIColor!
    var rgb:(Int?,Int?,Int?)!

    open var image: CIImage! {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    public var clearColor: UIColor! {
        didSet {
            myClearColor = clearColor
        }
    }

    public init() {
        let eaglContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        renderContext = CIContext(eaglContext: eaglContext!)
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        context = eaglContext!
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect, context: EAGLContext) {
        renderContext = CIContext(eaglContext: context)
        super.init(frame: frame, context: context)
        enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let eaglContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        renderContext = CIContext(eaglContext: eaglContext!)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        context = eaglContext!
        enableSetNeedsDisplay = true
    }

    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let image = image {
            let imageSize = image.extent.size
            var drawFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(drawableWidth), height: CGFloat(drawableHeight))
            let imageAR = imageSize.width / imageSize.height
            let viewAR = drawFrame.width / drawFrame.height
            if imageAR > viewAR {
                drawFrame.origin.y += (drawFrame.height - drawFrame.width / imageAR) / 2.0
                drawFrame.size.height = drawFrame.width / imageAR
        } else {
                drawFrame.origin.x += (drawFrame.width - drawFrame.height * imageAR) / 2.0
                drawFrame.size.width = drawFrame.height * imageAR
        }

            rgb = (0,0,0)
            rgb = myClearColor.rgb()
            glClearColor(Float(rgb.0!)/256.0, Float(rgb.1!)/256.0, Float(rgb.2!)/256.0, 0.0);
            glClear(0x00004000)
            // set the blend mode to "source over" so that CI will use that
            glEnable(0x0BE2);
            glBlendFunc(1, 0x0303);
            renderContext.draw(image, in: drawFrame, from: image.extent)
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes.

- I absolutely need to credit [Objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/photo-extensions/) for much of this. This is also a great resource for Swift and UIKit coding.
- I wanted AspectFit content mode with the potential to change the "backgroundColor" of the GLKView, which is why I subclassed and and called if clearColor.

Between the two resources I linked to, you should have what you need to have a good performing, near real time use of Core Image, using the GPU. One reason my afore-mentioned code to use scaling **after getting the output of a filter** was never updated? It didn't need it.

Lots here to process, I know. But I've found this side of things (Core Image effects) to be the most fun side (and pretty cool too) of iOS.

Comment: ah thank you for the insight! I tried changing "CIVector" to  "CGpoint" and it compiled, but it crashes as soon as the filter is is called since it doesn't actually recognize the syntax of the x or y. is there a proper way to convert CIVector to CGPoint?

Comment: It took me a while to "get" CIVectors too. A CIVector is simply a variable group of, uh, variables. :-) It may contain 2, 3, 4, even 9, depending on the filter requirements. According to the CIBumpDistorion doc, you want a CIVector(x,y) as the inputCenter. So **if** you have a CIPoint(35,152) - by stressing the "if" I'm saying it scales 1:1 - you turn it into a CIVector(35,152). But if the image size is scaled differently than the image view size, you need to recompute things.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation on CIVectors, I had no idea and just assumed they were a singular point like CGPoints. Any advice on going from touchesBegan to having a single X and Y CIVector that I can use for the filter center key?

Comment: I just added an explanation of scaling that may help.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! It helped out quite a bit. I'm surprised to learn that the Vector are based on the true size of the image and not based on the current size of the image view. based on your explanation I added *4 to x and y and have some promising results. only issue is on certain center keys the filter shifts the image quite a bit out of the frame so I can't tell if the filter was applied correctly with the new center key. I've been searching for a way to "clamp to extends" the image to its image view (I believe thats what its called?) the image in swift 3 with little luck.

Comment: If I'm reading this, you have good output "except". That's a good thing. Let me do some searching of CGContexts and drawing to a rect. That's all you are missing I believe. Also, I added a critical piece of scaling - the Y coordinate in Core Image is upside down from UIKit. (My first point in the original answer.)

Comment: How "real time" are you looking for? If you are updating a UIImageView via a CI filter, you probably want to consider using a GLKView instead. Core Image uses the GPU (as does a GLKView) but all UIViews (which UIImageView is a subclass of) use only the CPU. A one-time update (say via a UIButton tap) works well for this, but UISliders (or many "real time" gesture recognizers) won't.

Comment: I have an output thats doing something in relation to the touch now so thats good! If I press in the middle of the image, the filter center appears in the upper right of the image. unfortunately if I touch anywhere else it just squishes the entire image usually moving at least half of it out of the frame itself. either vertically squishing other other times horizontally. I also tried it with inverting y since you said y was the opposite in this context. it didn't have any effect though.

Comment: Update your question with the code you are now using. That might help.

Comment: I updated the code in the op and yes the goal is to be able to set the filter and then tap on the image as many times as needed to get the center where i want it. a GLKView sounds like the right solution to that if its not possible to do that with a normal image view.